# Getting wrong output when adding elements in 2D Array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I am studying C programming now, I am not getting correct output when I am adding two elements in array, i am expecting your help to know the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int limit = 0, sum[limit][3];
    int a[limit][3];
    int b[limit][3];

    printf("Enter the size of arrays: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    printf("Enter the values of Array 1");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Array 1: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Enter the values of Array 2");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Array 2: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
            sum[i][j]= a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("Sum of 2 arrays: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", sum[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Current output:

Enter the size of arrays:

```
3
```

Enter the values of Array 1

```
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
```

Array 1:

```
12  12  12  
12  12  12  
12  12  12
```

Enter the values of Array 2

```
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
```

Array 2:

```
11  11  11  
11  11  11  
11  11  11
```

Sum of 2 arrays:

```
22  22  22  
22  22  22  
22  22  22
```

The problem i found that the exact array i gave in code that doesn't workout.
My expected output is:

```
23 23 23
23 23 23
23 23 23
```

Comment: If your 2nd dimension is constant "3", and you're looping over this 3 items `limit` times, no wonder something goes wrong. Additionally, no wonder something goes wrong when `limit` is 0 when your sizing your arrays.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
int limit = 0, sum[limit][3];
int a[limit][3];
int b[limit][3];
```

`limit` is 0, your arrays will be:

```
int sum [0][3];
int a[0][3];
int b[0][3];
```

They will have space for nothing.

You should declare your arrays only after the `limit` input.

Also note that the second dimension of the array is fixed at `3`, in your inner `for` cycles, instead of using `limit` you should use that constant value, otherwise, if `limit` is 4 or more, your program will access the array outside its bounds, invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Great! got expected output.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- the arrays are defined with a dimension set to 0:

  ```
    int limit = 0, sum[limit][3];
    int a[limit][3];
    int b[limit][3];
  ```

you should define the arrays after you read the value og `limit`.

- the nested loops use an incorrect boundary test:

  ```
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
  ```

`j` should iterate from `0` to `3` excluded.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int limit = 0;

    printf("Enter the size of arrays: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &limit) != 1 || limit < 1)
        return 1;

    int sum[limit][3];
    int a[limit][3];
    int b[limit][3];

    printf("Enter the values of Array 1");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Array 1: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Enter the values of Array 2");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Array 2: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("Sum of 2 arrays: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", sum[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the inner nested loops,j should iterate till j(excluding it) not limit.
Required nested loop should be like-

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
.
.
}
```

Tip:Declare your array after getting the input/size of the array from the user.